# Using %in% operator on data frame cells

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, comparison-operators

Using the `%in%` operator, what would be the very equivalent of this subsetting operation `wantedSubset`?

```
dataset <- data.frame(
  "V1"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
  "V2"=c("green","yellow","blue","red","purple","black","white","gray")
)

# subset all cells containing the value 3 or the value "blue"
wantedSubset <- dataset == 3 | dataset == "blue"
```

I would like to do the operation `wantedSubset` differently by using the `%in%` operator. How & why can('t) I achieve this? (it seems that `%in` is applied on entire columns and not on each cell value?)

```
# will not return wanted result
dataset %in% c("3","blue")
```

Comment: What is the desired output here?  A vector? Cell indices?

Comment: A logical matrix. (The desired output is exactly what is given when you execute `wantedSubset`)

Comment: The `%in%` (unlike the `==` operator) doesn't have a `data.frame` method. Though you could do something like ```mapply(`%in%`, dataset, c("3","blue"))``` instead

Comment: Good comment @DavidArenburg. Is there a resource for this information? (plus, your solution works.)

Comment: Yes, I would start with reading `?S4groupGeneric`

Comment: Just to clarify @DavidArenburg’s comment: `%in%` *isn’t* a group generic, nor any kind of generic. But it can be *made* generic of course (the package S4Vectors does that, though there’s no need for S4; using S3 would be sufficient here).